# DNN9 "Add Module" Missing for Users in Custom Roles

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

When logged into a user with a custom-made role in DNN9, the "Add Module" button is missing from "Page Edit Mode", while "Add Existing Module" and "Page Settings" buttons are available.

How can you get the old <DNN9 "Add New Module" button to appear?

Actual Result:

[image: Actual Result]

Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some looking around, it seems that you need to go into each DNN extension that you want to be available to each custom DNN role and manually assign each custom role to each DNN extension.

I guess the good thing about this is that the "Add Module" popup looks clean with no unpopular modules cluttering the area up.

You can find the appropriate setting with the following instructions:

1. Go to: "Extensions/Edit Extension/Site Settings Tab"
2. Search for each role manually and "Add"
3. Make sure there is a checkbox ticked under "Can  Deploy" next to
   each role that you just added
4. Save the changes to the extension

Note that DNN9 may have a bug where the setting may not save and you may need to do this more than once to take affect.